# How to get extended metadata properties of a video file on windows server 2012 r2?

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-api-code-pack

I'm using WindowsAPICodePack to collect metadata properties of a video file. [Here is the github repo.](https://github.com/aybe/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1) internally it returns all the objects as you perform right click on file and see details information and properties. See below screenshot.

[image: Left side windows server and left side windows 10 extended video properties]

I can retrieve all the properties in my windows 10 machine. I expect the same behaviour on windows server 2012 r2 machine. The left side of image is contains properties from windows server and right side contains properties from windows 10 os. I'm unable to find anything relevant? What windows feature do I need to enable from windows server 2012 r2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one more library available if you don't want to install Windows Server essential mediapack. Here is the link and https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get all those properties after enabling desktop experience as shown in [this tutorial](https://yellowduckguy.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/windows-server-2012-how-to-add-desktop-experience-feature/). Initially windows server can not play video files. this feature adds video streaming facility and extra features that comes with [Windows server essential media pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40837)